# How to configure jmeter to run sampler tests through percentage of threads not all of them

Tags: jmeter

I would like to run multiple samplers with different frequencies. For example in a test plan I have two samplers A and B and I want to 80% of threads run sampler A and 20% of threads run sampler B. How can I configure this situation instead of running all thread on all samplers?

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way would be to use an [Interleave Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Interleave_Controller) and add Sampler A 4 times and Sampler B 1 time. But, that is *very, very dirty*.

A better way would be to use the [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller). Then you can execute Sampler A or B depending on a variable you can set and change on a test and thread basis. (Initialise per test and change per thread.)

The variable you need can be found under the Config Elements and is named [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm confused about changing variable value when running. How can I change this per thread? How should I use this Counter element for this mean?

Comment: The counter does that for your. The counter increments by *n* every thread.